# Emacs: How to enable toolbar mode and menubar mode only under a certain mode?

Tags: init-file, menu-bar

I use Emacs. However, I am not familiar with Lisp although I do know some functional programming, and hence I never really understood how to customize the `init.el`.

So basically, I want to be able to enable the toolbar mode and menubar mode only if I am in `R-mode`.

I know that to enable these mode simply requires:

`(tool-bar-mode 1)` and `(menu-bar-mode 1)`

but what if I want to do this locally, i.e. enable them only if I am in `R-mode`.

What should I put in the `init.el` ?

Comment: You posted the exact same question on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124095/emacs-how-to-enable-toolbar-mode-and-menubar-mode-only-under-a-certain-mode) at almost exactly the same time.  Please do not abuse the sites like this: people on Emacs.SE will not know about comments/answers on S.O. and vice-versa unless they happen to be checking both.

Comment: I didn't realise there was Emacs.SE until after I posted the question on StackOverflow. I am sorry about this.

Answer (score 5):

tool-bar-mode and menu-bar-mode being a global modes, you can enable them using a mode hook, but all buffers in all frames will be affected.

Never used it, but you may be interested by [toolbar-here-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/tool-bar+.el)

> In addition to defining minor mode `tool-bar-pop-up-mode`, this
>   library defines minor mode `tool-bar-here-mode`, which is the
>   same as the global `tool-bar-mode` except that it affects only
>   the current frame.

For menu-bar-mode, you have the `toggle-menu-bar-mode-from-frame` function:

> (toggle-menu-bar-mode-from-frame &optional ARG)
>
> Toggle menu bar on or off, based on the status of the current frame.
>   See `menu-bar-mode' for more information

And use it with a key, for example in your init file:

`(global-set-key [f2] 'toggle-menu-bar-mode-from-frame)`

Comment: `tool-bar-here-mode` and the pop-up tool bar of `tool-bar-pop-up-mode` are described [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ToolBar#tool-bar-pop-up-mode).